# Windows 10 not recognizing microphone in bluetooth headphones

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, boot-camp, microphone

I've tried connecting my AirPods Pro and my Bose QC35 headphones - both of which include a microphone. Windows 10 doesn't seem to pick up the microphone for either of them:

[image]

When I try to troubleshoot the Apple audio device above it says not plugged in. And The Bose won't even show up in the recording tab at all, even after selecting show disabled/disconnected devices. Does this have anything to do with the fact that I have an unactivated version of Windows 10? I got the ISO from the official Windows site though. Or could it have something to do with the fact that I'm running Windows 10 from bootcamp on a 2019 Macbook Pro 16"?

Related discussion on Apple forums where nobody found a solution:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250844237

Comment: "Does this have anything to do with the fact that I have an unactivated version of Windows 10? " Don't believe so. Are there drivers for the headphones and Windows? How many connections on the headphone plug, 3 or 4?

Comment: @Moab, not that I've been able to find. I found someone mention a Broadcom driver for AirPods a couple years ago, but the installation failed for me because it said it couldn't find any Bluetooth devices.

Comment: How many connections on the headphone plug, 3 or 4?

Comment: @Moab, sorry not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Moab, if  you mean physical wires - none. These are both connected via bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a known issue with no current workaround:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251232512

> On the new 16-in MBP (and older T2-controller Macs), this is a known
>   issue. The driver does not seem to recognize the Microphone side on
>   Windows. If I get a chance, I will try to debug the BT layer and see
>   what I can find.

Answer (score -1):

buying an additional usb BT dongle and disabling the built-in one solves this problem in Bootcamp. FYR.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).